# Why is there still a row limit in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, row-number, limits

Until Office 2007, Excel has a maximum of 65,000 rows. Office 2007 bumped that up to a max of 1 million rows, which is nicer of course; but I'm curious -- why is there a limit at all? Obviously, performance will slow down exponetially as you increase the spreadsheet size; but it shouldn't be very hard to have Excel optimize for that by starting with a small sheet and dynamically "re-sizing" it only as needed. 
   Given how much work it must have been to increase the limit from 65K to 1 million, why didn't they go all the way so it's limited only by the amount of available memory and disk space?

Comment: Seems like a question that can only be answered by Microsoft itself.

Comment: @Zach Scrivena, Looks like that isn't the case.  That, and we have some MS people here on SO.

Comment: Perhaps it is to make the tool more fool-proof. With 1 million rows it just takes a bit of effort to run out of memory or have something calculate forever (some nice vlookups or other complicated formulas should do). Without limits, you could fill up your memory just by filling a column 'to the bottom'. This would obviously result in a lot of situations where the conclusion of the end user will be `it doesn't work` and reduce the overall user experience.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Probably because of optimizations. Excel 2007 can have a maximum of 16 384 columns and 1 048 576 rows. Strange numbers?

14 bits = 16 384, 20 bits = 1 048 576

14 + 20 = 34 bits = more than one 32 bit register can hold.

But they also need to store the format of the cell (text, number etc) and formatting (colors, borders etc). Assuming they use two 32-bit words (64 bit) they use 34 bits for the cell number and have 30 bits for other things.

Why is that important? In memory they don't need to allocate all the memory needed for the whole spreadsheet but only the memory necessary for your data, and every data is tagged with in what cell it is supposed to be in.

**Update 2016:**

Found a link to [Microsoft's specification for Excel 2013 & 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f)

- Open workbooks: Limited by available memory and system resources
- Worksheet size: 1,048,576 rows (20 bits) by 16,384 columns (14 bits)
- Column width: 255 characters (8 bits)
- Row height: 409 points
- Page breaks: 1,026 horizontal and vertical (unexpected number, probably wrong, 10 bits is 1024)
- Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,767 characters (signed 16 bits)
- Characters in a header or footer: 255 (8 bits)
- Sheets in a workbook: Limited by available memory (default is 1 sheet)
- Colors in a workbook: 16 million colors (32 bit with full access to 24 bit color spectrum)
- Named views in a workbook: Limited by available memory
- Unique cell formats/cell styles: 64,000 (16 bits = 65536)
- Fill styles: 256 (8 bits)
- Line weight and styles: 256 (8 bits)
- Unique font types: 1,024 (10 bits) global fonts available for use; 512 per workbook
- Number formats in a workbook: Between 200 and 250, depending on the language version of Excel that you have installed
- Names in a workbook: Limited by available memory
- Windows in a workbook: Limited by available memory
- Hyperlinks in a worksheet: 66,530 hyperlinks (unexpected number, probably wrong. 16 bits = 65536)
- Panes in a window: 4
- Linked sheets: Limited by available memory
- Scenarios: Limited by available memory; a summary report shows only the first 251 scenarios
- Changing cells in a scenario: 32
- Adjustable cells in Solver: 200
- Custom functions: Limited by available memory
- Zoom range: 10 percent to 400 percent
- Reports: Limited by available memory
- Sort references: 64 in a single sort; unlimited when using sequential sorts
- Undo levels: 100
- Fields in a data form: 32
- Workbook parameters: 255 parameters per workbook
- Items displayed in filter drop-down lists: 10,000

Comment: What am I missing? I make that as 14 + 20 = 34

Comment: @jtolle: You are correct. It was too early in the morning (04:00).

Comment: @htm11h It doesn't matter if you have 4GB or 64PB, Excel still have a limit of 1048576 rows and 16384 columns. [source: Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f)

Comment: My source was for older Office versions

Answer (score 8):

In a word - speed.  An index for up to a million rows fits in a 32-bit word, so it can be used efficiently on 32-bit processors.  Function arguments that fit in a CPU register are extremely efficient, while ones that are larger require accessing memory on each function call, a far slower operation.  Updating a spreadsheet can be an intensive operation involving many cell references, so speed is important.  Besides, the Excel team expects that anyone dealing with more than a million rows will be using a database rather than a spreadsheet.

Comment: That make no sense. Sure, a million row index fits in 32 bits...but so does 4 billion rows. Why not go up to that?
   As for the database argument -- clearly people felt hampered by 32K rows and they had to raise it to 64k in excel 97. Then they raised it to 1M in Excel 2007. Why not go all the way?